# vLANs from Switch SMC 8748M to Dell PowerConnect 6248

Tags: configuration, switch, dell, vlan

I currently have a stack of SMC 8748M switches (total of 4).  I'm using 2 VLAN on it (1 and 2).  What I have so far :

- a trunk between SMC and Dell switches, (2 ports trunk).

When I put a single port on a vLAN #1 on Dell switch, it is not recognized as the same VLAN #1 as on the SMC switches.

I have seen somewhere to enable GVRP, but I am not sure..

I would like to know how to do that on both side.

Regards,
David.

Answer (score 1):

On the bonded ports, set vLAN 1 and 2 to tagged (on both units).

Comment: Also, Check that the actual VLAN id is the same.  Names of a VLAN don't necessarily correspond to the actual VLAN id (tag).

Comment: I have checked both side vlan's id and everything fits.. I am also wondering if I should set my normal ports (not trunked ports) to tagged or untagged.  Also, when everything is default (on vlan 1) it ping well, but as soon as I put 2 unit (1 on SMC's and 2nd on Dell's) on VLAN #2, they don't ping eachother.

Comment: The "other" ports should be untagged. Only trunk ports should be tagged (for most configurations)